# How to get image name and image type uploaded in froala editor?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I uploaded the image in froala editor, but I am not getting the image name and image type in ajax. How can I move that file to my own server using laravel?

In ajax:

```
let editor = new FroalaEditor('div#edit', {}, function () {});
```

By using this I am getting the file name as a string.

In Laravel Controller:

```
  $dom = new \DomDocument();
   $dom->loadHtml($issue_description, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    
   $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($images as $k => $img){
       $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
        list($type, $data) = explode(',', $data);
       list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
       $data = base64_decode($data);
       $image_name= "/upload/" . time().$k.'.png';
       $path = public_path() . $image_name;
       file_put_contents($path, $data);
        $img->removeAttribute('src');
       $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);
   }
```

This is how I handle it.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost Froala Editor provides very detailed documentation one of the things I easily picked from their docs is the script below:

```
<script>
    new FroalaEditor('#edit', {
      // Set the file upload URL.
      imageUploadURL: '/upload_image.php',

      imageUploadParams: {
        id: 'my_editor'
      }
    })
  </script>
```

What this means is that you need to write a function or a class that oes the Image Upload Service . Whenever Froala Uploads an image it perfoms an Ajax request to your Url or route in your case laravel.

One it reaches Laravel then in your controller or function, you can do:

```
$image = $request->file('name_of_file') or using raw PHP   $filename = explode(".", $_FILES[$fieldname]["name"]);
```

Your function should then return a response with a URL String of the Uploaded Image an example below:

```
E.g.: {"link":"http://server_address/uploads/name_of_file"}.
```

Comment: if i am changing this imageUploadURL: '/upload_image.php', i am getting something went wrong error when image is uploaded in froala editor

Comment: Hi Aparna - when you are changing that image upload URL, please show me the routes and the controller associated with it .. Lets see the Method or function you are using in your laravel .